# Python Binary Summation

Tags: python, performance, binary, sum, sage

While looking at some SageMath code I came across the following snippet:

```
bits = n - sum(n.digits(2))
```

Since I had no idea what `digits`did I went ahead to attempt it with a value of `n = 5`:

```
n = 5
print(n.digits(2))
[1, 0, 1]
```

And if I run the complete line the result is (rather obviously)

```
n = 5
print(sum(n.digits(2)))
2
```

How could I achieve this in pure python? Conversion to strings and back are dead slow, so I'd like to avoid those. Is there a fast solution to this?

Comment: You are looking for the number of bits to 1 in a number ?

Comment: The sum of all the individual bits of a number (therefore the number of 1's in a number's bit representation). *e.g:* 5 -> 101 -> 1+0+1 -> 2

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to the number of non-zero bits :

```
bin(5).count("1")
```

Comment: I think it will perform even better if you remove `[2:]` which creates a new list.